# How to have ASP.Net TemplateField with Label and Checkbox with manually added row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following asp:GridView

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="contacts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ContactID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("employerdetailcontactid") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Action"  ItemStyle-CssClass="center" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("action") %>' />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Action" runat="server"  />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="First Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Last Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="E-Mail">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Phone Number">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("phonenumber") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Send E-mail"  ItemStyle-CssClass="center" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SendEmail" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean( Eval("sendemail")) %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

The GridView has however many rows from the database, plus one extra row for adding a new row.  Very rarely will the end-user ever add more than one contact at a time, so I am not going to bother having an "Add Row" button.  I want the rows from the database to have the label say "Delete" and the manually added row have the label say "New".  Here is my code to populate the GridView:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *,'Delete' as action FROM contact WHERE employerid=@employerid", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employerid", id);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //These are added to be able to manually add a row below
    dt.Columns.Add("ContactID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Action");
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Email");
    dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");
    dt.Columns.Add("SendEmail");

    dt.Load(dr);


    DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
    drow["ContactID"] = 0;
    drow["Action"] = false;
    drow["FirstName"] = "";
    drow["LastName"] = "";
    drow["Email"] = "";
    drow["PhoneNumber"] = "";
    drow["SendEmail"] = "False";
    dt.Rows.Add(drow);

    contacts.DataSource = dt;
    contacts.DataBind();
```

How would I set the text of ActionLabel to "New" for the manually added row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Attach for the RowDataBound event and programmatically set the text

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Action"  ItemStyle-CssClass="center" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("action") %>' />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Action" runat="server"  />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

//use the onItemDatabound

  void contacts_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
        
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // get contact id to identify whether this is fake row
      int contactId = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ContactID"));
      string labelText = contactId > 0 ? "Delete" : "New";
      ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("ActionLabel")).Text = labelText;
    }
  }
```

2. Option 2: Use FooterRow template and enable footer row in the GridView component

```
<asp:GridView ShowFooter = "true"
...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Action"  ItemStyle-CssClass="center" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Action" runat="server"  />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text="New" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Action" runat="server"  />
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am a little confused whether I modified the right GridView column, but I think you'll get the idea

Comment: The first solution had an error.  The second solution worked perfectly.